# Restrict user to enter/delete any alphabets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ace-editor

I am trying out the ACE Editor with AngularJS (using [UI-Ace](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace)). I have a query.
Can I restrict the user

1. Not to enter any character except for a predefined char (say ;)
2. Not to delete any character except for the predefined char or space

UI-Ace on angular exposed the onChange event of ACE editor as follows:

```
$scope.aceChanged = function(e) {
//
};
```

In php we just checked the entered char does not match the specified char list/array/expression/ascii, but how can I get the character being changed/entered/deleted in this.

Please guide.

Edit:
I am trying as per a user's ans: but I am getting error like editor variable undefined  or  lines undefined

```
$scope.aceLoaded = function(_editor) {
    // Options
    //_editor.setReadOnly(true);
    //editor.setOption("showPrintMargin", false)        
    _editor.setOption("showPrintMargin", false);
    //_editor.setShowInvisibles(true);
    var _session = _editor.getSession();

    //_session.setUseSoftTabs(false);

    //editor.on("change", onchange)
    _editor.commands.on("afterExec", afterExec);

  };

  var revertScheduled = false;

  $scope.aceChanged = function(e) {
    if($scope.startt ==0){ $scope.startt = new Date().getTime()};
    if (!revertScheduled && _editor.curOp) {
        var text = e.data.lines
            ? e.data.lines.join("\n")
            : e.data.text;

        var shouldRevert = false;
        var isInsertion = e.data.action[0] == "i";
        if (isInsertion && !/^[;]+$/.test(text)) {
            shouldRevert = true;
        } else if (!isInsertion && !/^[; ]+$/.test(text)) {
            shouldRevert = true;
        }

        if (shouldRevert) {
            editor.session.mergeUndoDeltas = false
            editor.session.markUndoGroup()
            revertScheduled = true
            console.log(e.data.text, editor.curOp)
        }
    }
      //
    $http({
        url: global.apiurl+"splitrec",//"http://medline.dev/api/splitrec",
        method: "POST",
        data: {'record': $scope.record.name}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here
            //$log.log(data);
        $scope.res = data;
        $scope.prova();

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $log.log(status);
        });
  };


var onchange = function(e) {

}

var afterExec = function() {
    if (revertScheduled) {
        editor.undo();
        revertScheduled = false
    }
}
```

my log output of e: (curOP is null)

```
[Object, y]
 0: Object
    data: Object
    action: "insertText"
    range: i
    text: "r"
    __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
 1: y
    $blockScrolling: 0
    $enableMultiselect: true
    $highlightPending: false
    $historyTracker: function () { [native code] }
    $isFocused: false
    $mouseHandler: l
    $multiselectOnSessionChange: function () { [native code] }
    $onAddRange: function () { [native code] }
    $onChangeAnnotation: function () { [native code] }
    $onChangeBackMarker: function () { [native code] }
    $onChangeBreakpoint: function () { [native code] }
    $onChangeFold: function () { [native code] }
    $onChangeFrontMarker: function () { [native code] }
    $onChangeMode: function () { [native code] }
    $onChangeTabSize: function () { [native code] }
    $onChangeWrapLimit: function () { [native code] }
    $onChangeWrapMode: function () { [native code] }
    $onCursorChange: function () { [native code] }
    $onDocumentChange: function () { [native code] }
    $onMultiSelect: function () { [native code] }
    $onRemoveRange: function () { [native code] }
    $onScrollLeftChange: function () { [native code] }
    $onScrollTopChange: function () { [native code] }
    $onSelectionChange: function () { [native code] }
    $onSingleSelect: function () { [native code] }
    $onTokenizerUpdate: function () { [native code] }
    $opResetTimer: function (e){n==null&&(n=setTimeout(r,e||t))}
    $search: o
    _$emitInputEvent: function (e){n==null&&(n=setTimeout(r,e||t))}
    _defaultHandlers: Object
    _eventRegistry: Object
    commands: o
    container: div.ng-valid.ace_editor.ace-chrome.ng-dirty
    curOp: null
    env: Object
    keyBinding: s
   lastFileJumpPos: null
   mergeNextCommand: true
   multiSelect: u
   prevOp: Object
   previousCommand: null
   renderer: g
   selection: u
   selections: Array[5]
   sequenceStartTime: 1399493671829
   session: p
   textInput: f
```

Please guide

Answer (score 1):

if you can get access to real ace instance, you can use the following method

```
var revertScheduled = false
var onchange = function(e) {
    if (!revertScheduled && editor.curOp) {
        var text = e.data.lines
            ? e.data.lines.join("\n")
            : e.data.text;

        var shouldRevert = false;
        var isInsertion = e.data.action[0] == "i";
        if (isInsertion && !/^[;]+$/.test(text)) {
            shouldRevert = true;
        } else if (!isInsertion && !/^[; ]+$/.test(text)) {
            shouldRevert = true;
        }

        if (shouldRevert) {
            editor.session.mergeUndoDeltas = false
            editor.session.markUndoGroup()
            revertScheduled = true
            console.log(e.data.text, editor.curOp)
        }
    }
}

var afterExec = function() {
    if (revertScheduled) {
        editor.undo();
        revertScheduled = false
    }
}
editor.on("change", onchange)
editor.commands.on("afterExec", afterExec)
```

which tests if the change is something to dissallow, and reverts it.

Comment: could you explain how we are Not to enter any character except for a predefined char (say ;) and please explain var shouldRevert = e.data.lines
            ? e.data.lines.length > 3 
            : /([dr])/.test(e.data.text)

Comment: Sorry, i assumed you are only unfamiliar with ace api and can handle regex yourself. I've updated the example to do exactly what you described in the question: test if inserted/removed text matches to the list of allowed characters, and revert change if it doesn't.

Comment: please see my code, I have added it in my ques. There seems to be problem. It is not able to get the editor.CurOp

Comment: Could you make online demo, say with jsbin? I think you are either using old version of ace, or your editor variable isn't instance of the   ace but a wrapper object from UI-Ace.